# Domain with $\cosh(x)$

Tags: functions

Take the function
$$y=\frac{\sqrt{\cosh\left(\frac{1+x}{x^2}\right) - 1}}{e^{\frac{2}{x-1}\log\left|x-1\right|}+1}$$
I have to find the domain of this function. These are the condition that I set up:
$$\begin{cases}
e^{\frac{2}{x-1}\log\left|x-1\right|}+1\neq 0&(1)\\
x-1\neq0&(2)\\
\left|x-1\right|>0&(3)\\
\cosh\left(\frac{1+x}{x^2}\right) - 1\ge0&(4)\\
x^2\neq0&(5)
\end{cases}$$
And these are the results:
$$\begin{cases}
\forall x \in\mathbb{R}&(1)\\
x\neq1&(3)\\
\forall x \in\mathbb{R}&(4)\\
x\neq0&(5)
\end{cases}$$

$(1)$ Denominator

$(2)$ Denominator of the exponent
$(3)$ Argument of the logarithm
$(4)$ Argument of the root
$(5)$ Denominator of the argument of $\cosh$

And this is the definition set of $y$:
$$x\in(-\infty, 0)\cup(0, 1)\cup(1, +\infty)$$

I deleted $(2)$ because it's included in the $(3)$.

The $(1)$ is verified for all $x$ because it's an exponential and because I set up the $(3)$

To solve $(3)$ I made the $\vee$ between $x-1<0$ and $x-1>0$.
The $(4)$ is verfied for all $x$ because the range of $\cosh(x)$ is $[1;+\infty)$, so it's always greater or equal than $1$.

So, is it correct? Or I was wrong something?

Comment: Looks right; you can do (3) a lot easier by noting that $|a|\geq 0$ for all $a$, and $|a|=0$ if and only if $a=0$; so in order to get $|x-1|\gt 0$ you only need $x-1\neq 0$; that is, (2) and (3) are equivalent. Note that "The (4) is verified for all $x$ because the **range** of $\cosh(x)$ is $[1,\infty)$" (range, not domain).

Comment: Yeah, I did :) Thank you Arturo!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*This CW answer intends to remove this question from the Unanswered queue.*

---

As [Arturo Magidin remarks](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/105068#comment246434_105068), your answer is correct. Cheers!